# Jinja2 Templating: Conditionally forming a set from Ansible Variables

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am trying to generate some config using Jinja2 templating and Ansible variables. The framework under which I am currently working does not allow me to perform the following operation in Ansible and thus I was hoping to achieve the same results in Jinja2.

My Ansible variables are as follows:

```
---
Top:
  inner:
    type: type1
    other_random_variable:
     - random: 1
  inner2:
    type: type2
  inner3:
    type: type1
```

The above structure works well when I am iterating over a loop and forming a configuration file as follows:

```
{% if Top is defined %}
{% for inner_vars in Top %}
# perform substitution here
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

What I would like to do is to form a set of types such that I can generate another configuration for each unique type.

Is there any way for me to iterate through `Top` and add an item to a set?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer to this question is no, however, not 100% sure. But even if it were possible, it would be nicer and neater if you built your own module(in python) where you pass your `Top` format it and return it in the way you want it.

Comment: Hey, I posted a sample solution that I believe would solve my problem. Please let me know if you have any other suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: that looks nice indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a solution that could work:

```
{% set types = [] %}

{% if Top is defined%}
{% for inner_var in Top %}
    {% if types.append(Top[inner_var].type) %}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{{ types|unique }}
```